# aiohttp: Unclosed client session warning?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm writing some code to concurrently make multiple POST requests to an API service. It works nicely, although I get the following warnings from aiohttp:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x119340130>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x119347520>, 9.057307166)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x119340190>
```

Here's the code I'm using to run it (note that they are snippets of methods in a class):

```py
    ...

    async def _request(self, ctx: dict, key: str):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
            await s.post(
                self.endpoint,
                json=ctx,
                headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % key}
            )
            return

    async def _gather_requests(self, key: str):
        await asyncio.gather(*[self._request(ctx, key) for ctx in self._contexts])

    async def _create_tasks(self):
        key = await self._get_key()
        await self._gather_requests(key)

    def trigger(self):
        asyncio.run(self._create_tasks())
```

I know that a common answer for this problem is to use a context manager which is what I've implemented, and I've also tried manually closing the connection with `s.close()`, and I still get the same issue. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: It looks like you are creating a new session for each post. i.e. lots more sessions open that need to be closed.  Also you are using await s.post rather than the aiohttp documentation ```async with```, see https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request